# Is there an easy way to compare floors and ceilings? Eg, is it true that $\lfloor{\frac{n}{k}}\rfloor\leq\lceil{\frac{n+1}2}\rceil$ for $k\geq 2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I want to see if for all $n, k \in \mathbb{Z}, k \geq 2$,
$$\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{k}}\right\rfloor \leq \left\lceil{\frac{n+1}{2}}\right\rceil$$
I've checked a bunch of numbers with some basic python, but how would I show this mathematically?

Edit: I have a lot more inequalities like this to show, so I'd love to also know the method you would use. Thanks!

Comment: Is the denominator in your second fraction supposed to be $2$?  Or should it be $k$?

Comment: If $n=k=-1$ your statement is false. Is it $n, k\in \mathbb N$?

Comment: Also, if you allow for $k=1$ you run into more problems. For $n=5$ and $k=1$ your claim doesn't hold

Comment: However if $n \in \mathbb N$ and $k \in \mathbb N \setminus \{1\}$, the result is quite trivial.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I meant to put $k \geq 2$

Comment: @paw88789 The 2 is correct

Comment: For $n\geq 1$ and $k\geq 2$ one has $$ \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \right\rfloor \leq \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor \leq \left\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2} \right\rfloor \leq \left\lceil \frac{n+1}{2} \right\rceil  $$

Answer (score 0):

The statement does not hold... Even if $n,k \in\mathbb{N}$, in the case $k=1$ you would have to show that
$$
n \leq \left\lceil \frac{n+1}{2} \right\rceil
$$

and this is just nor true. If $n,k \ge 2$ the result holds. To check that, just need to show that it holds for $k=2$, because for larger $k$ the LHS is even smaller.

Considering any $k \ge 2$, the result does not hold for in general for negative $n$. For instance, if $k\ge 4$, the result only holds for $n\ge -2$.

Comment: sorry meant to do for $k \geq 2$

Comment: @JohnSmith If $k \ge 2$, the result holds trivially for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Like I said, check directly  for $k=2$ (see what happens for odd and even $n$) and note that if $k>2$ the inequality also holds (the rhs is the same and the lhs is smaller).